# Google Now ignoring my Other calendars

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-now, nexus-5

When I ask Google Now to tell me my appointments, it tells me appointments from some of my calendars, but not Other ones added from URL. How can I get it to recognise these other calendars?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Sync your Google Calender after you add the events to your calender.

> Settings>Google Account>Sync Calender

After that refresh Google Now, it should show the calenders.

Comment: As I said, my calendars are already synced, that's why Google Now is telling my appointments from my main calendars. My question is how to get it to take appointments from my Other calendars.

Comment: Is your other calender from another Google Account of your own or a separate Google account?

Comment: My other calendar is imported by URL into my own Google Account.